# Difference between table renaming and exchange partition

Tags: sql, oracle, etl, database-partitioning

I have an ETL process which loads the data into a target table A. We have created another table B which is same as the target table in structure 
and this table is accessed by reporting team to generate reports. Now whenever data is loaded into target table A, stored procedure is invoked to rename the table B as table Temp, table B as table A and table A as table Temp. This is done to minimize the downtime for report generation.

This way the reports are always accessing the latest data. Now my question is I can create a partition on table B and use exchange partition mechanism to swap the segments of A and partitioned table B. So can you tell me which is a better approach and how different is exchange partition from table renaming.

Comment: @George Is it possible to have two partitions P1 and P2 on target table and ETL process loads data into patition P1 of target table and then using exchange partition can we swap partition P2 with partition P1. P1 wl be used for ETL and P2 will be used for reporting...Is this design something possible using Exchange Partition mechanism??

Answer (score 1):

When you are renaming tables object which statically refer on these tables may become invalid. So I would prefer to use exchange partition.

Another benefit of exchange partition method is that tables A and B could have different grants: A is target table with read grants to final users, B - is intermediate table accesses only by application.

They also could have different indexes - B does not require indexes at all.

Table A could store all historical data (in partitions) and B holds only currently generated intermediate data (non-partitioned).

Comment: I agree, and if I have the Partitioning option I'd prefer exchange partition even when the partitioned table has only one partition.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually they are the same. Only metadata gets modified.
However by using exchange partition.
1. You have the option of gathering statistics on the partition.(a smaller subset compared with the full table)
2. Archiving of old data become easy. (You can archive partitions older than 3 years for example)

You can check the following link on asktom for more information.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1238800184155,%7Bpartitions%7D

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to appreciate that a table is an object with a set of inherent logical metadata (name, grants, etc.) combined with a data object (and the data object's metadata, such as the number of rows and other statistics).

When you rename a table, you are potentially modifying everything about the object that that table name string resolves to -- all the table metadata, the data object and its metadata -- and that has important implications for the rest of your system. You are now pointing to a different object.

When you exchange partitions, you are changing the data object associated with the table object. This inherently has less impact on the rest of your system, as the table's metadata remains untouched and you are still pointing to the same logical object.

For this reason I would prefer the partition exchange to the table rename.

p.s. Using this metaphor, you might also consider a view object to be logically pretty much the same as table object because they both have similar logical metadata. The view, of course, does not have a data object, and instead has extra metadata to define its underlying relation.

Materialised views are also like tables, with additional metadata (similar to views), and with extra metadata for refresh purposes.

A table with deferred segment creation is a table object for which no data object has yet been created.

etc.